# Due to a bug in Eigen/GCC 4.7 - is ROS available on Saucy?

Tags: eigen, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Due to the cause of this bug: https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_setup_assistant/issues/60 ... I'd like to know how difficult it will probably be to install ROS on a Saucy system. Or, if it's not yet recommended to walk this way, what kind of problems might arise from upgrading my 32bit Raring to 32bit Saucy with ROS still installed.

Has anybody tried installing the ROS packages from Raring on a Ubuntu Saucy? Is it compatible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91921/due-to-a-bug-in-eigen/gcc-4.7---is-ros-available-on-saucy?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-10-17**:
An alternative to upgrading Ubuntu would be to get the bugfix of Eigen backported to the current release, opposed to completely upgrading Eigen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the answers to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/91631/can-we-install-ros-hydro-on-ubuntu-1310/) and the target platforms for ROS Hydro: http://ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#hydro-medusa-apr-2013

It seems like there will be no binary ROS release for 13.10, which means you might have to install everything from source. Is a re-installation of 13.04 64-bit or the 12.04 LTS an alternative?

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2013-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-10-17**:
I've seen that question already and was just wondering if the Raring binaries might work on Saucy too. I'm preparing to reinstall 64bit. Currently making a backup of my whole harddisk. I fear that I'm gonna have to walk through my graphics driver issues all over again after installing 64bit...